# How to debug JavaScript / Typescript in VSCode using Bun.sh

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, debugging, bun

I have recently started playing with [Bun](https://bun.sh/) to run typescript files without compiling them to js. So far so good. Eventually I wanted to debug at runtime but couldn't find anything about it in the [docs](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun#readme).

How can I configure my `.vscode/launch.json` file to debug a project using bun?

I tried playing around with a configuration but didn't get very far:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Bun",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "bun",
            "runtimeArgs": ["run"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Looking through the [official roadmap](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/159), I see nothing about debugging, but maybe it is an experimental feature at this point?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible yet.
There is an open enhancement request for adding a [runtime debugger](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/1106).

Comment: I was able to achieve full debugging following the official vscode bun extension from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oven.bun-vscode

Answer (score 5):

It is possible now. Install the [1st party extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oven.bun-vscode).

The extension explainer shows suggests a launch.json and settings.json to enable the command "Bun: Run File".

For me I had my bun installed as a devDependancy, and out-of-the-box the extension could not find the runtime, so I modified the settings.json as follows:

```json
{
    // The path to the `bun` executable.
    "bun.runtime": "node_modules/bun/bin/bun",
    // If support for Bun should be added to the default "JavaScript Debug Terminal".
    "bun.debugTerminal.enabled": true,
    // If the debugger should stop on the first line of the program.
    "bun.debugTerminal.stopOnEntry": false,
}
```

With that in place run "Bun: Run File" would work with the the debugger